# Question about the definition of compact topological space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> A topological space X is called compact if each of its open covers has
>   a finite subcover.
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space

The finite subcovers are also open covers of $X$ so there are finite subcovers for finite subcovers and so on. When we get to the smallest integer $J$ for which the subcover $\{ U_j|j\in J\}$ is still a cover of $X$, there is no another subcover for this cover and therefore not all of the open covers of $X$ have subcovers. So the $X$ is not compact - a contradiction. What is wrong with my reasoning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any cover is trivially a subcover of itself. If your cover is finite you are done. If your cover is not finite but has a finite subcover you are done.

Answer (score 6):

A subcover doesn't have to be a proper subcover

Answer (score 6):

An open cover is a subcover of itself, because every set is a subset of itself.

Answer (score 3):

your reasoning is wrong! :D 
The inclusion need not to be proper: if the cover is finite you can trivially choose it as a finite subcover.