# Can a subcover of a cover be treated as a cover in itself

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

The definition of a compact set says every open cover has to have a finite subcover. Does that mean that the subcover is supposed to be different from the cover? Also in case some cover has a some finite subcover, isn't the subcover also a cover and that would imply the subcover also have to have another finite subcover and thus infinitum?

Edit : Seems my question is a repeat of the following question
[Question about the definition of compact topological space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334200/question-about-the-definition-of-compact-topological-space/334202#334202)

So essentially my question is all to confirm the fact that the finite subcover need not be proper?

Comment: No, each cover is a subcover of itself, like each set is a subset of itself. So when you have a finite subcover with no _proper_ subcover, your infinite chain of subcovers becomes stationary.

Comment: Each space $X$ can be covered by $\{X\}$ and this open cover does not have a proper subcover.

Answer (score 3):

The finite subcover doesn't have to be different from the cover itself if the cover is finite. It is analogous to saying that $A$ is a finite subset of $B$. If $B$ is a finite set, we could have $A = B$. In fact, this is hardly an analogy, but rather a restatement of the problem where $A$ is the indexing set of the subcover and $B$ is the indexing set of the cover.

A subcover is indeed a cover (just like a subset is a set). Suppose $\mathcal{U} = \{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a cover of a compact set $K$, then it has a finite subcover $\{U_{i_1}, \dots, U_{i_n}\}$. This is again a cover of $K$, so it has a finite subcover, namely itself.

Comment: So can the definition of a compact set be interpreted as saying every infinite cover has to have a finite subcover, since any finite cover anyway is a finite subcover of itself?

Comment: You could state it that way yes. If you do that then every subset of a set with finite topology is vacuously compact as there are no infinite covers.

Answer (score 1):

When we say that $\cal u$ is a subcover of $\cal V$ we simply say that $\cal U\subseteq V$ and $\cal U$ is a cover.

In particular $\cal V$ is a cover and it is a subset of itself. Therefore every cover is a subcover of itself.